# Fatal error while parsing XML using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I want to parse a XML file. It throws the Exception while creating object:

```
Document doc = builder.parse("Response.xml");
```

Exception:

```
[Fatal Error] Response.xml:63:67: The prefix "UDF" for element "UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST" is not bound.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "UDF" for element "UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
    at tallyreqandresponse.Ledger.main(Ledger.java:38)
Java Result: 1
```

Sample xml Code:

```
 <A>
 <LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
   <NAME.LIST TYPE="String">
       <NAME>ABC India (P) Ltd.,</NAME>
   </NAME.LIST>
   <LANGUAGEID TYPE="Number"> 1033</LANGUAGEID>
   <UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST DESC="`RTSIDUDF`" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="Number">
       <UDF:RTSIDUDF DESC="`RTSIDUDF`"> 1387</UDF:RTSIDUDF>
   </UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST>
   </LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
 </A>
```

Kindly help me out of it.

Edit Note: Added LANGUAGENAME.LIST Opening tag

Comment: You need xmlns with description of UDF namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input markup is not namespace well-formed XML so it is rejected by the XML parser. You need to fix the input with e.g.

```
<A>
 <NAME.LIST TYPE="String">
       <NAME>ABC India (P) Ltd.,</NAME>
 </NAME.LIST>
 <LANGUAGEID TYPE="Number"> 1033</LANGUAGEID>
       <UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST xmlns:UDF="http://example.com/" DESC="`RTSIDUDF`" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="Number">
                      <UDF:RTSIDUDF DESC="`RTSIDUDF`"> 1387</UDF:RTSIDUDF>
      </UDF:RTSIDUDF.LIST>
  </LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
</A>
```

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ for the format specification. Also note that `xmlns:UDF="http://example.com/"` is meant as an example, I don't recognize your format so I can't relate a URL with it.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the missing namespace definition it also seems that there is a mismatched tag:

```
</LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
```

has no corresponding opening tag.

If you Google `xml namespaces` you get plenty of good links - have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp) for example.